# MYSQL GROUP By + ORDER BY FIELD()

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Have tree table:

**Emails_blocks**

```
blocks_id  blocks_pos  url_type  blocks_folder  
1          1           1         emails_block   
2          2           1         emails_show    
3          3           1         emails_add     
4          4           0         emails_share
```

**Emails_blocks_text**

```
texts_id  blocks_id  langs_code  
2         1          ru          
1         1          ua          
3         2          ua
```

**Emails_blocks_aliases**

```
blocks_id  aliases_name  
1          news          
2          drafts
```

And have query:

```
SELECT `blocks_id`,  `blocks_folder`, `blocks_name`, `aliases_name`, `langs_code`
FROM `a_emails_blocks`
LEFT JOIN `a_emails_blocks_text` USING(`blocks_id`)
LEFT JOIN `a_emails_blocks_aliases` USING(`blocks_id`)
GROUP BY `blocks_id`
ORDER BY FIELD(`a_emails_blocks_text`.`langs_code`, 'ua', 'ru')
```

But on result I have on blocks_id = 1 **not langs_code 'ua', I have langs code 'ru'.**
I dont understand why dont ordering from enother table.

```
blocks_id  blocks_folder  aliases_name  langs_code 

1          emails_block   news          ru          
2          emails_show    drafts        ua          
3          emails_add                               
4          emails_share
```

Comment: Is your GROUP BY for a particular reason - are there multiple records returned per blocks_id that you are trying to collapse to the first found record?

Comment: Yes. I want get all rows without dublicate on blocks_id.

Comment: I think part of the problem is down to the GROUP BY. For example with block_id 1 you have multiple matching records on Emails_blocks_text, which results in 2 rows with different values of langs_code. Following the GROUP BY which one of those 2 langs_code that is returned will be fairly random. Which one would you like to be returned and used for the ordering? Further the ordering seems a bit strange as FIELD should return 0 for non found strings, so the last 2 records should be returned first in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `SELECT` only fields you have in `GROUP BY` or aggregated result

Actually in you case you don't need `GROUP BY` because you don't have any aggregated functions(sum, count,avg etc)

Comment: And how i can delete dublicated rows blocks_id = 1 ??

Comment: DISTINCT will remove duplicates. But the problem is that you do not truely return duplicates as a block_id of 1 would result in 2 rows each with a different langs_code. Which one of the langs_code is returned would be random, and to be meaningful you need to define which one is returned.